# How to initialize a 2d array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, declaration, c-strings

I am trying to figure out a way to initialize my 2d string array and Iwanted to know if there is a better way of doing it than what I have coded below.

Is there also a way to not provide the size of the array as I will be writing to it later on, so I do not know the size (currently set to size 30).

Example of array content at a later stage : "Football","Rugby","Tennis"

```
char sports_array[30][81];

int i;

for (i=0; i<30; i++){
  strcpy(sports_array[i],"");
}
```

The problem with this is that if the array only holds 2 values, then I will have to still loop through the rest (size 30) which I don't want as these will be empty. I need the array to adjust depending on how many values it holds later down the line.

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: Do you want to be able to modify the content of a single string or only assign different constant strings to your array?

Comment: Hi @Kolodez. I will be only assigning values to the array and wont be modifying the content.

Comment: Yes, there are better ways to initialize the array. Which way(s) are best depends on circumstances, such as how the array will be used. Initializing the first byte of each (outer) array element to the null character might suffice. But using a separate counter to count how many array elements are in use might be better. There is insufficient context in the question to answer that. As for setting the size of the array later, you likely need to use dynamic allocation using `malloc`. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service for that.

Comment: `strcpy(sports_array[i],"");` is same as `sports_array[i][0] = '\0';` . Nothing to worry about, using `strcpy` is fine for this, just saying in case you are not aware.

Comment: @hyde: `strcpy(sports_array[i],"");` is not the same as `sports_array[i][0] = '\0';`. The latter stores a null character in `sports_array[i][0]`. The former nominally calls a subroutine, passing it two pointers, loads a character via the second pointer, stores it in `sports_array[i][0]`, tests it, branches out of a loop, and returns.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah ok, thanks for your response. I will look deeper into malloc.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That seems like the same thing to me (after good optimizations, at least). What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over all indices.

In case of pointer (`char*` or `char**`) you can test for the condition `NULL`, in case of an char array (`char[]`) you can test for `'\0'`.

In your case (`char sports_array[30][81] = {""}`) you could do the following:

```
for (int i=0; sports_array[i][0] != '\0'; ++i) { ... }
```

Hence discarding all empty strings.

If you work with fixed size arrays (`char[]`), allways initialize with `""`, `{""}` or `{'\0'}`.

If you want to work with `malloc` and friends (therefore using char pointers - `char*` or `char**`), always make sure to initialize the pointers with `NULL` (either manually or `calloc`).

If you can guarantee that your pointers (strings) are proper initialized, testing for either `NULL` or `'\0'` can (and mostly) should be the condition for any loop.

Answer (score -1):

In the declaration of the array you could write for example

```
char sports_array[30][81] = { "" };
```

in this case all characters of the array are zero-initialized.

If you want to reinitialize it such a way that each element of the array would contain an empty string then you can write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
{
    sports_array[i][0] = '\0';
}
```

Then you can write for example

```
strcpy( sports_array[0], "Football" );
strcpy( sports_array[1], "Rugby" );
strcpy( sports_array[2], "Tennis" );
```

If you want to allocate strings dynamically then you can declare the array like

```
char * sports_array[30] = { 0 };
```

In this case all elements of the array will be null pointers.

If you do not know how many strings the array will contain then you can declare a pointer like

```
char **sports_array = NULL;
```

and then  use the function `realloc` when a new string is added to the array.

Comment: "in this case all elements of the array are zero-initialized" -- Are you sure? If zero-initialization is not needed, this behavior would be a real waste of CPU time.

Comment: @Kolodez No, I am not sure. I just know this.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for your suggestion. I will try have a look into malloc so I can set the array size after knowing how many values I will have.

Comment: @Steven Alternatively you can use calloc to set elements of the allocated arrays to zero.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, if I want an array declaration without initialization, how would I do this?

Comment: @Kolodez Just write char sports_array[30][81]; provided that the array has automatic storage duration. Otherwise it will be zero-initialized.